# Change parent state from child component doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Parent component:

```
state = {
   value: 0
}

add() {
   let { value } = this.state

   value++

   this.setState({ value: value})
}

remove() {
   let { value } = this.state

   value--

   this.setState({ value: value})
}

render() {
   return(
      <Child add={this.add} remove={this.remove} />
   )
}
```

And child component:

```
...

render() {
   const { add, remove } = this.props

   return(
      <div>
         <button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>
         <button onClick={() => remove()}>Remove</button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

I want to update `value` state in my Parent component, when I click buttons inside Child component. But when I try to do this in this way, I receive error:

> Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

What I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: bind you function with this

Comment: Create your add and remove fucntion as arrow functions: add = () => ...

Comment: Have a look at the docs -> https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appear because your methods lose the binding with `this`. There is two way for solving this.

#### Arrow functions

With es6, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to define function autobinded with `this`, like that:

```
add = () => {
   let { value } = this.state

   value++

   this.setState({ value: value})
}

remove = () => {
   let { value } = this.state

   value--

   this.setState({ value: value})
}
```

#### bind function

In the `constructor` of your component, you can specify explicit binding using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Child add={this.add.bind(this)} remove={this.remove.bind(this)} />
```

like this

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is works, but I prefer answer with an arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your methods or use arrow function. Unlike a regular function, an arrow function does not bind this. Instead, this is bound lexically. This keeps it's meaning from it's original context

```
export class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    }

    add() {
     let { value } = this.state

      value++

      this.setState({ value: value})
    }

   remove() {
      let { value } = this.state

      value--

      this.setState({ value: value})
   }
    // arrow function
    someFuncion = () => {
     this.setState({ value: 0})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fat arrows to get `this` reference inside function. 
 In your case,

```
state = {
   value: 0
}

add = () => {
   let { value } = this.state

   value++

   this.setState({ value: value})
}

remove = ()=> {
   let { value } = this.state

   value--

   this.setState({ value: value})
}

render() {
   return(
      <Child add={this.add} remove={this.remove} />
   )
}
```